# MYSQL query syntax - unknown column error but column exists

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM families f JOIN family_histories fh ON f.id = fh.family_id
WHERE f.family_status_cat_id = 1422
AND (SELECT hst.created_at
     FROM family_histories hst 
     WHERE hst.family_history_cat_id = 1422 
     AND hst.new_value LIKE '%1422%')
BETWEEN '2010/2/13' AND '2013/3/6'
```

I get -

> Unknown column 'hst.new_value' in 'where clause'

. 
But the column exists!!!

Comment: this simply means `family_histories` has no column named `new_value`

Comment: what happens if you remove condition "AND hst.new_value LIKE '%1422%'" does it still give you error?

Comment: Your syntax is not correct... joined tables and clause `between` are not connected

Comment: Somehow the last closing parenthesis should not be there. Copy/paste mistake?

Comment: I think you dont need subquery because you already have joined families table with family_histories table. What are you trying to do with subquery. Syntax too is wrong. as mentioned by @Justin

Comment: @Sebastian - copy/paste mistake

Comment: @JW. You were right. Column name is: new_val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM families f
  JOIN family_histories fh
    ON f.id = fh.family_id
WHERE
  f.family_status_cat_id = 1422 AND
  fh.created_at BETWEEN '2010-02-13' AND '2013-03-06' AND
  fh.family_history_cat_id = 1422 AND
  fh.new_value LIKE '%1422%'
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If the column name is new_val then you should have below query

```
SELECT * FROM families f
JOIN family_histories fh
ON f.id = fh.family_id
WHERE
 f.family_status_cat_id = 1422 AND
 fh.created_at BETWEEN '2010-02-13' AND '2013-03-06' AND
 fh.family_history_cat_id = 1422 AND
 fh.new_val LIKE '%1422%'
```

You wont need second select which you have currently in your query. Its the same query as mentioned by Devart.